# Is there a way to make UNR not to maximize all windows I open?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, gnome, ubuntu-netbook-remix

Ubuntu Netbook Remix maximizes all windows I open, including dialog windows (e. g. find dialog). That's frustrating. Is there a way to change the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found how you can do that. Here's [the clue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maximus/+bug/362301). Unfortunately there was a typo in the command, so I had to stumble a little, until I guessed why nothing had happened.

That's how to make `maximus` do the right thing:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/maximus/no_maximize --type BOOL true
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to disable [maximus](https://launchpad.net/maximus).

Go to `system`->`preferences`->`sessions` and disable it or open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get remove maximus
```

in order to uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, first, I found it under System -> Startup Applications -> Startup Programs. Second, it didn't work as I expected. Now windows are not maximized at all, the way like UNR does it by default, hiding the window title. I'd like to leave that maximize feature, but I don't want it to maximize all windows I open. Is it possible?

Comment: It seems that maximus has an exclude list. Take a look here: http://albertsq.blogspot.com/2008/09/maximus-configuration.html

Comment: For me, it's more comfortable to just maximize windows I want than to configure every single window that maximus maximizes improperly.